# dplyr works differently for dataframe and database - how to resolve?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, dplyr

Apparently, dplyr requires different implementation for dataframes and databases.
This is not the first time I encounter this.
The example code is below. The purpose of the code is to remove `Inf` values from the database.

```
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)

# dataframe
data <- data.frame(x = c(rep(1,2), rep(Inf, 3), rep(1, 5)),
                   y = c(rep(2,5), rep(Inf, 5)),
                   z = 1:10)

# database
db <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(db, data, name = "data", overwrite = TRUE)

data_db <- tbl(db, "data")

# WORKS for dataframe:
data %>% filter_at(c("x", "y"), all_vars(base::is.finite(.)))

# DOES NOT WORK for database
data_db %>% filter_at(c("x", "y"), all_vars(base::is.finite(.)))
```

The last line returns an error:

```
Error in eval_bare(call, env) : object 'x' not found
```

Is there a good overview of the differences required in implementations of dplyr for dataframes vs. databases?

Please help to have the code above work for the database case.
Thank you

Comment: Before anything else I suggest upgrading to the latest version of ‘dplyr’, and replacing superseded functions by their modern equivalent (i.e. replace `filter_at` by a combination of `filter` and `across`). This may *still* behave differently on data in memory vs DBS, but I expect there to be much fewer differences. (Actually, I don’t think if `across` currently has *any* DBS support, nor if it needs it.)

Answer (score 2):

Looking through `dbplyr`'s [Function translation vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/translation-function.html), it doesn't look like `is.finite()` is mentioned, and indeed we can verify that it doesn't know how to translate `is.infinite` to the SQL command `ISFINITE()`.

```
dbplyr::translate_sql(is.infinite(x))
# <SQL> is.infinite(`x`)
```

In this case, as per the [Writing SQL with dbplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/sql.html) vignette, you can use the `sql` command, something like:

```
## write idea, but probably won't work
data_db %>% filter(across(c("x", "y"), sql(NOT ISFINITE(.))))
```

Though that admittedly looks like it has a low chance of working because of the `.` in the SQL. I'm not sure how well `across()` (or the older `filter_at`) `dplyr` functions play with the `sql()` function. You may need to write out the columns you want to filter on:

```
data_db %>% filter(sql(NOT ISFINITE(x)), sql(NOT ISFINITE(y)))
```

> Is there a good overview of the differences required in implementations of dplyr for dataframes vs. databases?

The vignettes mentioned above are both good reading on this.

Comment: There should be a way to search for the 'Inf' value in the sql db, even if your sql engine likely doesn't understand it, it must be read by it one way or anther, it can pe pull'ed/select'ed after all.

Comment: @Sirius Right, `ISFINITE` is the SQLite command, as I show in the `sql()` function. The issue is that SQLite will expect `ISFINITE(column_name)`, not `ISFINITE(.)`. I doubt `dplyr`'s `across()` and the `purrr`-style anonymous function work well with expressions in `sql()` that are passed directly to the database. So OP will probably need to use `filter(sql(ISFINITE(x)), sql(ISFINITE(y)))` instead, or something like that. I'll edit to make the final recommendation explicit.

Comment: Well yes, propagating the many dplyr verbs seemlessly into sql certainly would be a tall order. But ISFINITE tests Inf for what it is not , eg finite. Is there a way to test Inf specifically for what it is, in what ever form it is represented in the inmem db?

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I didn't realize I had switched `is.infinte` to `ISFINITE`. I'd probably just use the `NOT` keyword to negate `ISFINITE`.

Comment: Getting error: `Error: no such function: ISFINITE` when running `data_db %>% filter(sql("ISFINITE(x)"), sql("ISFINITE(y)"))`

Answer (score 1):

You could turn it into a proper data.frame or tibble:

```r
data_db <- tbl(db, "data") %>% as_tibble

# WORKS for dataframe:
data %>% filter_at(c("x", "y"), all_vars(base::is.finite(.)))

# DOES NOT WORK for database
data_db %>% filter_at(c("x", "y"), all_vars(base::is.finite(.)))
```

Output:

```
> data %>% filter_at(c("x", "y"), all_vars(base::is.finite(.)))
  x y z
1 1 2 1
2 1 2 2
> data_db %>% filter_at(c("x", "y"), all_vars(base::is.finite(.)))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     2     1
2     1     2     2
```

You could use `as.data.frame` instead of `as_tibble` if that is more to your liking.

Comment: For most purposes this defeats the point of having a database.

Comment: I agree with this

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out (almost).
The problem with SQLite is that it does not have function ISFINITE causing `Error: no such function: ISFINITE` (as I posted in the comment to Gregor's answer).

My solution is to use basic math logic to define Inf:

```
> data_db %>% filter(sql("x * x != x or x = 0 or x = 1"),
+                    sql("y * y != y or y = 0 or y = 1"))
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 3]
# Database: sqlite 3.33.0 [:memory:]
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     2     1
2     1     2     2
```

The only thing is that I could not figure out how to make this work with `filter(across(c("x", "y"))`